# How to hide a border when a navigation element is selected

Tags: css

I'm creating a navigation bar (in a div) that has a vertical list. When you click on an element in the navigation, it pops up a div that touches the nagigation list. This div has a border (getting rid of that border looks weird, so i'm not doing that). How do I remove a part of that border (the part that touches the selected navigation div)?

A little more explanation: The pop-up div touches the nav on the left side. I want to hide the border for only the section of the border touching the selected element in the nav bar

FOUND A SOLUTION:
I needed to put a right-border: -1px on the navigation in order to cover the border on the pop-up div.

Comment: Do you have code samples, a live preview, or images we could consult?

Comment: Being new, i can't add an image, and I can't link to an example. Sorry.

A little more explanation:
The pop-up div touches the nav on the left side. I want to hide the border for only the section of the border touching the selected element in the nav bar

Answer (score 1):

if it touches the nav with its top ... use `border-top: none`

Comment: It touches the nav on the left side. I want to hide the border for only the section of the border touching the selected element in the nav bar.

Comment: so I suppose you have to use `border-left:none`. If I think of something wrong, I will need the code to completely understand you.

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION: I needed to put a right-border: -1px on the navigation in order to cover the border on the pop-up div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Outline:0px;` or `Border:none;` on that part. but cant say unless i see the code.